# Editing Stored Procedures in MSSQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I imported a database for MSSQL 2008 for development. I know they have stored procedures because I was able to edit them live with the web interface front that they have.

Now that I have the database loaded in a development location how do I access them? Are they normally stored in a table? I see at least one table with stored procedures. Is there a way to edit them with a built in text editor?

EDIT: I do have SQL Management Studio installed, just not sure how exactly to access/edit the procedures.

Comment: [Use SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) then see [Modify a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345356.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

So different from working with MySQL.

1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine and
   then expand that instance.
2. Expand Databases, expand the database in which the stored procedure
   belongs, and then expand Programmability.
3. Expand Stored Procedures, right-click the procedure to modify, and
   then click Modify.
4. Modify the text of the stored procedure.
5. To test the syntax, on the Query menu, click Parse.
6. To modify the stored procedure, on the Query menu, click Execute.
7. To save the script, on the File menu, click Save As. Accept the file
   name or replace it with a new name, and then click Save.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use SSMS - SQL Server Management Studio to do this. Its usually included with SQL Server, so you may just need to install it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx

or download it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

If You Installed SQL SERVER Management Studio then Type `ssms` in `RUN`

1. Select Installed SQL SERVER Instance and Log in
2. Then Type Below command, it gives you Text of stored procedure

> sp_helptext 'Procedure_name'